# Relative days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to create a view on top of DimCalendar/DimDate dimension to get following [Relative Days] column -

[image]

If today is 10/6 - Friday, then my relative days is 0. Tomorrow is Saturday which is a weekend the we should not consider it as a Business day. Hence it would still be 0. Same thing applies for Sunday. From Monday on wards it will increase.

If we go back, the number should be negative. It should also consider weekends.

Can someone help me to write  a SQL code to populate Relative Days column that would change based on today?

**UPDATE**

I tried this but didn't work.

```
cast((DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), c.Date) + 1) - (DATEDIFF(wk, GETDATE(), c.Date) * 2) -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - (CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, c.Date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as int) [Relative Days]
```

Thanks

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS which u r using.

Comment: But the relative day column would change everyday.

Comment: Yes. I will be creating a view for this. I just need a formula to get the Relative Days

Comment: If you search the internet for "calendar table" you will find many discussions about how to create and populate them. One of the uses is to define with certainty which days are "work" days. Why? Because it seems that this is what you really need - all your "relative" date logic depends on that knowledge and is trivial to determine (probably - but who knows from what you posted). And one thing you assume is that every non-weekend day is a work day. Real life is very different. Does that matter here? Again - who knows.

Comment: And to continue with that comment - you can find functions that will dynamically create the same work day calendar (with or without the real-life messiness caused by natural disasters, etc.).

Comment: Side note: I probably wouldn't do this, or rather, I wouldn't store a relative offset like this.  Consider: how many days do you need "relative" days for?  How many columns would that be?  Rather, what I would store is "work day count", which is an absolute offset from some point, and would be the same for all days.  Then, to find the "relative offset", I'd subtract/add the relevant number of days to the current row, and query based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query for the calculation

```
DECLARE @Today DATE= '20171006'
SET DATEFIRST  1

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CalendarDate, 
        WD = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CalendarDate) IN (6,7) THEN 0 ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CalendarDate) END ,
        W = DATEPART(WEEK,CalendarDate) ,
        BeforeAfterConstant = CASE WHEN CalendarDate < @Today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM @Calendar
)
SELECT 
    CalendarDate,
    [Day] = DATENAME ( WEEKDAY, CalendarDate ),
    RelativeDays = 
            ( 5 - DATEPART( WEEKDAY, @Today ) ) 
            + ( (W - DATEPART( WEEK, @Today ) - ( CASE WD WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) ) * 5 )
            + CASE WHEN WD = 0 THEN BeforeAfterConstant ELSE WD  END
 FROM CTE
```

Result:

```
CalendarDate Day                            RelativeDays
------------ ------------------------------ ------------
2017-09-26   Tuesday                        -8
2017-09-27   Wednesday                      -7
2017-09-28   Thursday                       -6
2017-09-29   Friday                         -5
2017-09-30   Saturday                       -4
2017-10-01   Sunday                         -4
2017-10-02   Monday                         -4
2017-10-03   Tuesday                        -3
2017-10-04   Wednesday                      -2
2017-10-05   Thursday                       -1
2017-10-06   Friday                         0
2017-10-07   Saturday                       0
2017-10-08   Sunday                         0
2017-10-09   Monday                         1
2017-10-10   Tuesday                        2
2017-10-11   Wednesday                      3
2017-10-12   Thursday                       4
2017-10-13   Friday                         5
2017-10-14   Saturday                       5
2017-10-15   Sunday                         5
2017-10-16   Monday                         6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select cal.*,
       (cume_days -
        max(case when caldate = '2017-10-06' then cume_day end) over () 
       ) as relative_days
from (select cal.*,
             sum(case when day in ('Saturday', 'Sunday' then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (order by caldate) as cume_days
     from cal
    ) c;
```

However, you cannot make this a column in the table -- it changes every day.  You can, however, put the calculation in a view.

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: @RameshwarPawale . . . The downvote is rude and you don't explain what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for that. In my case, I'm supposed to get -4 value for 10/1 (Sun) and 30/9 (Sat) whereas I'm getting -5 value with your query.

Comment: I hope you understood my problem.